# Return multiple rows on a single record

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to retrieve this result:

```
ROW1.id | ROW2.id | ROW3.id | ROW4.id
   1    |    2    |    3    |    4
```

starting from this result `select * from Table`:

```
id | value
1  | sample1
2  | sample2
3  | sample3
4  | sample4
```

any idea?

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: do you have only 4 id's or you want to pivot the table for all distinct id's found.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like that:

```
select 
 (select id from table X where X.something = 123) as row1Id,
 (select id from table X where X.something = 456) as row2Id,
 (select id from table X where X.something = 789) as row3Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into SQL's [pivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)