# Return multiple rows based on int value from a single record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table containing project data with one record for each project. Below some sample data, duration is in months and is currently limited to max. 240, but can, theoretically, be infinite:

```
id  name       amount  start_date  duration
1   Project A   9.000  2013-06-24    3
2   Project B   5.000  2013-07-13    2
3   Project C  15.000  2013-08-06    3
```

Now I want MySQL to return the amount per month for each project: amount divided by duration for each month starting with the month the start_date is in. So based on the above data, MySQL will return something like below, ordered by month:

```
id  name       month    amount_this_month
1   Project A  2013-06    3.000
1   Project A  2013-07    3.000
2   Project B  2013-07    2.500
1   Project A  2013-08    3.000
2   Project B  2013-08    2.500
3   Project C  2013-08    5.000
3   Project C  2013-09    5.000
3   Project C  2013-10    5.000
```

I saw something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601134/return-multiple-rows-on-a-single-record) for SQL Server, giving the suggestion to use a dummy table filled with numbers. Anyone has any ideas on how to do this without affecting the original database structure?

I need to do this in one query (so no temp (mem) tables).
How is this possible in MySQL? I saw some solutions for Oracle to iterate trough a (virtual) range/sequence, is it possible to do something like this in MySQL?

Comment: Q: Why I want to do this in one single query, no temp/mem tables?
A: I need to add this as a part of a single SQL query that will be dynamically generated by a closed source module on a system I'm currently experimenting/testing on.

Comment: It is possible to do this with MySQL. I would be more inclined to help if you showed me what you have tried so far, and why it failed.

Comment: A table of integers is the easiest way to do it, and it is useful for other things. However you can have a subselect of fixed values unioned together to get a range of numbers, and join that against itself to get larger ranges. Something like (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9)

Comment: @YaK - I tried the 'table of integers' solution as a temp implementation. But I am preferably looking for a solution that won't affect the whole db structure... Haven't thought of joining fixed number selects as others suggest now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, joining a dummy range of numbers against itself to get the range of numbers, then adding that to the base month

```
SELECT id, name, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL Units.i + Tens.i * 10 + Hundreds.i * 100 MONTH), '%Y-%m') AS `month`, (amount / duration) AS `amount_this_month`
FROM SomeTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Units
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Tens
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Hundreds
WHERE (Units.i + Tens.i * 10 + Hundreds.i * 100) < duration
```

Comment: Wow, haven't thought of joining fixed number selects. Great solution, will try it directly...